# Retornar pedaços de um iterável

Tags: python, funções

Implemente uma função de gerador, `chunker`, que recebe um iterável e retorna um pedaço de tamanho específico por vez. Recorrendo à função assim:

```
for chunk in chunker(range(25), 4):
    print(list(chunk))
```

deve resultar na saída:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6, 7]
[8, 9, 10, 11]
[12, 13, 14, 15]
[16, 17, 18, 19]
[20, 21, 22, 23]
[24]
```

Estou com dificuldades mais uma vez nesse assunto sobre geradores no Python. Eu consigo executar o código, mas não com a saída desejada. Eu não estou conseguindo criar as colunas como ele pede na questão, só consigo contar os elementos com `range()`.

Este foi meu código :

```
def chunker(iterable, size):
    num = size
    for item in iterable:
       yield item,size


for chunk in chunker(range(25), 4):
    print(list(chunk))
```

Que gerou essa saída:

```
[0, 4]
[1, 4]
[2, 4]
[3, 4]
[4, 4]
[5, 4]
[6, 4]
[7, 4]
[8, 4]
[9, 4]
[10, 4]
[11, 4]
[12, 4]
[13, 4]
[14, 4]
[15, 4]
[16, 4]
[17, 4]
[18, 4]
[19, 4]
[20, 4]
[21, 4]
[22, 4]
[23, 4]
[24, 4]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update da versão 3.12**

Na versão 3.12 do Python foi adicionada a função [`itertools.batched`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.batched) que retorna um iterável de tuplas de tamanho definido:

```py
import itertools

for chunk in itertools.batched("Stack Overflow", 4):
  print(chunk)
```

A saída será:

```
('S', 't', 'a', 'c')
('k', ' ', 'O', 'v')
('e', 'r', 'f', 'l')
('o', 'w')
```

**Para versões anteriores a 3.12**

A solução do Miguel funciona, mas possui limitações. A primeira é que é necessária converter o gerador para lista ao passar como parâmetro, o que já fere o solicitado no enunciado, que especifica que o parâmetro é iterável (e não somente uma lista). Chamar apenas `chunker(range(25), 4)` produz já o retorno esperado, mas é uma particularidade do tipo `range` (ele implementa os métodos *mágicos* de forma a gerar alguns resultados sem consumir o gerador, tal como `__len__`). Para outros geradores a solução pode não funcionar:

```
def gerador():
    nome = "Stack Overflow"
    for char in nome:
        yield char

def chunker(iterable, size):
    for i in range(0, len(iterable), size):
        yield iterable[i:i+size]

for chunk in chunker(gerador(), 4):
    print(list(chunk))
```

Resultando em:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 10, in <module>
  File "python", line 7, in chunker
TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
```

A melhor solução seria utilizar a função [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) em conjunto com a função `itertools.islice`:

```
def chunker(iterable, size):
    it = iter(iterable)
    return iter(lambda: list(islice(it, size)), [])
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/AccurateVibrantCryptocurrency) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/h5LgDh)</sup>

Assim, a saída seria:

```
['S', 't', 'a', 'c']
['k', ' ', 'O', 'v']
['e', 'r', 'f', 'l']
['o', 'w']
```

Ou, para o exemplo da pergunta:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6, 7]
[8, 9, 10, 11]
[12, 13, 14, 15]
[16, 17, 18, 19]
[20, 21, 22, 23]
[24]
```

Comment: Estava agora a trabalhar numa solução para não ter de transformar a entrada em uma lista. Boa solução

Comment: Estamos aí para isso :D

Comment: Anderson nota que coloquei list(range(25)) de propósito (sei que não preciso com range), mas desta maneira implementaria o teu `gerador()`, `chunker(list(gerador()), 4)` por ex. A tua solução é melhor independentemente disso, o maior problema da minha é ter de facto de transformar em lista

Answer (score 4):

Podes fazer o seguinte:

```
def chunker(iterable, size):
    for i in range(0, len(iterable), size): # percorremos o nosso range com um step de 4 neste caso, [0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24]
        yield iterable[i:i+size] # ficamos com os valores do nosso iteravel contidos no intervalo entre i e i+size, na primeira volta entre 0 e 0+4 ([0,1,2,3]) na segunda entre 4 e 4+4 ([4, 5, 6, 7]), etc...

c = chunker(list(range(25)), 4)
print(list(c)) # [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23], [24]]
```

Fazes o loop sobre este gerador assim:

```
for i in chunker(list(range(25)), 4):
    print(i)
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://ideone.com/REbHRo)

Comment: obrigado , só com esse código já funcionou :

Comment: def chunker(iterable, size):
    for i in range(0, len(iterable), size):
        yield iterable[i:i+size]

Comment: De nada @CleomirSantos

Answer (score 2):

A partir do [**Python 3.12**](https://docs.python.org/3.12/whatsnew/3.12.html) (outubro de 2023) é possível usar a [função `itertools.batched`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/itertools.html#itertools.batched), que serve justamente para retornar pedaços de um iterável, um por vez.

Como esta função gera tuplas e você quer listas, basta fazer a conversão na hora de imprimir. Algo assim:

```py
from itertools import batched

for chunk in batched(range(25), 4):
    print(list(chunk))
```

Mas se quiser uma função que já gere as listas, bastaria trocar para:

```py
from itertools import batched

def chunker(iterable, size):
    yield from map(list, batched(iterable, size))

for chunk in chunker(range(25), 4):
    print(chunk)
```

Ou seja, `map` converte cada tupla para uma lista, e eu uso [`yield from`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0380/) para delegar a execução para o *generator* criado por `map`. Eu até poderia fazer algo como `for chunk in map(list, batched(iterable, size)): yield chunk`, mas `yield from` vai além e [já cuida de vários outros detalhes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26109157) (que estão além do escopo da pergunta, veja o link para mais informações).

Com isso a função continua sendo um *generator* (gera uma sub-lista por vez), veja:

```py
c = chunker(range(25), 4)
# "c" é um generator
print(c) # <generator object chunker at 0x7fbd645ed7b0>
import inspect
print(inspect.isgenerator(c)) # True

# imprime somente a primeira sub-lista (as demais não são geradas se não for necessário)
print('next =', next(c)) # next = [0, 1, 2, 3]

# imprime o restante
for n in c:
    print(n)
```